# jquery / php and File uploads to remote site

Tags: php, jquery, file, upload

This is my First post so please be gentle.

I am trying to streamline some B2B, but our supplier isn't helping, so I'm trying to create an interface using their standard web controls and a click by a user on my side via the browser.

The remote server has some nice security protocols so curl is out of the question. The only way I could get the remote server to accept my file was by making the interface via a web browser using their cookies. Which isn't a bad thing because I would like the staff to view the document before its posted.

When I use Fiddler and I do an upload via their site the Content Length the file size is 55344, The file size is 54920 so that's about right... But when i do it through Java / PHP / jquery they are all about 99870 in size.

If i upload a Text file this works fine.

If i upload a PDF or a Word Document the file size blows out and corrupts.

I have tried to create the post data via PHP and the jquery has a tanty and wont send, I have encoded and decoded base 64 between PHP and Java.. File size blows out

I have been googling for a few days now and not having much luck. Why would this be ?

Here is my Code for the JavaScript:

```
    var boundary = "' . $boundary . '";

    var jqxhr = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "' . $filename . '",
        context: document.pdf,
        global: false,
        async:false,
        success: function(data) {
            return data;
        }
    }).responseText;


var javabody = "--" + boundary + "\r\n"
        + "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"' .$name. '\"; filename=\"' .$filename. '\"\r\n"
        + "Content-Type: application/pdf\r\n\r\n"
        + jqxhr + "\r\n"
        + "--" + boundary + "\r\n"
        + "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"attachDocument\"" + "\r\n\r\n"
        + "Attach Docs\r\n"
        + "--" + boundary + "--";

    $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "' . $url . '",
            datatype: "html",
            contentType: "multipart/form-data; boundary=' . $boundary . '",
            cache: "false",
            context: document.body,
            global: "false",
            data: javabody,
            crossDomain: true,
            xhrFields: {
                    withCredentials: true
                    },
            processData: false,
            async: false,
            });
```

Everything works, 'a' file goes up and the placeholders and the boundary's are correct, Just the file size blows out and becomes corrupt.

Any help would be appreciated

Mike

Comment: Do you have access to the remote server?

Comment: The only access i have is via the web interface, It looks like its a tomcat server

Comment: is FTP enabled? I think it would be easier to send the file to the local server, do what logic is needed, open ftp protocols, and put put the file.

Comment: I was hoping that too, but the only interface we have with these guys is the Web interface. We have been trying to get an API from these guys with no luck for over a year. We upload 1000's of documents like quotes, Invoices etc every week. So this would be a REAL time saver for our Date Entry crew. I have done similar stuff with our notes that need to go on the site its just this is the last bottle neck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After brainstorming and searching this site until my fingers bled I come up with a solution:

```
function submitQuoteSupportingDoc() {
    //add the binary file contents to the object, can only submit file contents via post if binary blob is present
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "' . $filename . '", true);
    xhr.responseType = "blob";
    xhr.onload = function(e) {
            if (this.status == 200) {
                    var myBlob = this.response;
                    var fd = new FormData();
                    fd.append("attachFile", myBlob, "' . $FileForUpload . '" );
                    fd.append("attachDocument", "Attach Docs");
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "' . $DocumentUrl . '",
                        data: fd,
                        async: false,
                        crossDomain: true,
                            xhrFields: {
                                    withCredentials: true
                                    },
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false
                    }).done(function(data) {
                           console.log(data);
                    });
                    close();
                    }
    };
    xhr.send();
I}
```

Obviously this is running in a PHP script.. But it works.

Thanks Guys

Mike